# Add to cart not working on Woocommerce Category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im trying to get the add to cart feature on a category page
have already done Ajax enable in setings

https://verdealmendrado.cl/categoria-producto/frutossecos/

don´t now what to do.

Many thanks

I try looking for some code and plugins to achive but couldn solve it.

I was expecting to thet on clicking on the icon of the cart on any product in the category page the url with site/product/?add-to-cart=ID but i only get site/product/

Answer (score 0):

class for cart icon it is returning the product permalink. Have you modified or written this code somewhere? If not then please share the template file for product. If this code is coming from your theme then please find the file with this name inside your theme file directory - archieve-product.php and please paste the code here. Then i can help you out with further steps to solve it

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.